# Setting Frequency Domain in libgdx FFT

Tags: android, signal-processing, fft, fftw, libgdx

I'm new to Fourier Transforms, so can someone explain what I need to do to replicate this behaviour in fftw:

```
double* timeDomain = static_cast< double* >( fftw_malloc( sizeof( double ) * SEGMENTATION_LENGTH ) );
fftw_complex* frequencyDomain = static_cast< fftw_complex* >( fftw_malloc( sizeof( fftw_complex ) * ( ( SEGMENTATION_LENGTH / 2 ) + 1 ) ) );    
fftw_plan forward = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d( SEGMENTATION_LENGTH, timeDomain, frequencyDomain, FFTW_MEASURE );
```

using [libgdx's FFT class](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/audio/analysis/FFT.java?r=1298)

I'm assuming that I'll want to initialize my FFT object thus:

```
//2048 is smallest power of 2 larger than SEGMENTATION_LENGTH
FFT fourier = new FFT(2048,44100);
```

but I can't find any methods relating to the frequency domain. I can do `fourier.forward(samples)`, but it doesn't take any other parameters. Can someone give me a hint as to what I need to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got the solution, there's a `backward` method of `FFT` that takes the frequency domain real and imaginary values that you can get after calling `forward`.